# Testing Rails helper with Rspec: undefined local variable or method `request'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have a helper method that uses 'request' to determine the URL. However, rspec can't seem to find request. I thought request was available to all front-facing tests?

How can I account for the request method in my spec?

**Helper Spec**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ApplicationHelper do
    describe "full_title" do
        it "should include the page title" do
            expect(full_title("help")).to include('help')
        end
    end
end
```

**Helper methods**

```
def full_title(page_title)
    if staging? # causing the issue
        base_title = "Staging"
    else
        base_title = "Company Name"
    end

    if page_title.empty?
        "#{base_title} | Tag line "
    else
        "#{base_title} | #{page_title} "
    end
end

def staging? # the request here seems to be the problem
    request.original_url.include? "staging"
end
```

**Rspec error**

```
Failure/Error: expect(full_title("help")).to include('help')
    NameError:
        undefined local variable or method `request' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ApplicationHelper_2::FullTitle:0x00000106260078>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off: `request` is only available in the controller tests (and even then only in the request specs I think), helper tests are really basic and isolated. Which is good. Your helper code should be really minimal and normally only work on the input it receives. 
However this is pretty easily solvable by using stubbing.

So write something like

```
#note, OP needed to replace 'helper' with 'self'for Rails 4.0.0 and Rspec 3.0

require 'rails_helper'

describe ApplicationHelper do
  describe "full_title" do
    context "in staging" do
      it "should include the page title" do
        helper.should_receive(:staging?).and_return(true)
        expect(full_title("help")).to include('help')
      end
    end
    context "not in staging" do
      it "should include the page title" do
        helper.should_receive(:staging?).and_return(false)
        expect(full_title("help")).to include('help')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Which is imho a very clear, and then you write separate tests for your `staging?` method:

```
  describe "staging?" do
    context "when in staging" do
      it "returns true" do
        helper.stub(:request) { OpenStruct.new(original_url: 'staging') } 
        expect( helper.staging? ).to be true
      end
    end
    context "when not in staging" do
      it "returns false" do
        helper.stub(:request) { OpenStruct.new(original_url: 'development') } 
        expect(helper.staging?).to be false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Some small remarks: ruby default indentation is 2 spaces. 
Secondly, your function now literally says `return true if true`, ideally it should be written like

```
 def staging?
   request.original_url.include? "staging"
 end
```

Comment: Thanks, @nathanvda. Points duly noted at the end there. As for the full answer, your syntax isn't working for me. 'when' and 'helper' aren't recognized, so I've changed them to 'describe' and 'self', which works when staging returns true, but not when it returns false. I can't make anything in the second suggestion work. Any ideas?

Comment: Okay, switched it to expect... .to be_truthy and be_falsey. All green now. Thank you so much.

Comment: Sorry, indeed, the when was wrong and the `be_true` should be `be true` or `be_truthy`, whichever you prefer. `helper` used to be available, if your spec-file is defined in `spec/helpers` folder. From the [docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-0/docs/helper-specs/helper-spec) you should now add `require 'rails_helper'` for it to work, I think.

Comment: In my projects it is still called `spec_helper` :)